# Multiplication of floating numbers to a modulus

Tags: modular-arithmetic, floating-point

As we all know, the integers follow the following identity :

$$(A\cdot B\cdot C) \bmod M = ((A\cdot B) \bmod M\cdot C) \bmod M$$

But it does not work for real numbers having fractional part. For example:

$$1.7\cdot 1.7\cdot 1.7 = 0.913 \bmod 2.0$$

whereas,

$$1.7\cdot 1.7 = 0.89 \bmod 2.0$$

and, $0.89\cdot 1.7 = 1.513 \bmod 2.0$

We see the two results are unequal. So, does the modular identities do not work with real numbers? If yes, is there any way I could do multiplication of real numbers to get the expected result?

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question, the modular identities don't work by the counterexample you provided.

Comment: There is also a second question! I am looking for a workaround perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

They do not work this way.  In your example, we have $1.7 \cdot 1.7 = 2+0.89$ and $1.7 \cdot 1.7 \cdot 1.7 = (2+0.89)\cdot 1.7 = 3.4 + 0.89 \cdot 1.7$.  The reason it works with integers is the term that wound up $3.4$ here would have been an even integer, so could have been ignored when working $\pmod 2$

For reals I don't know of a workaround.  It really depends on the "granularity" of the integers.